# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 PYTHON

Tags: python, numpy

When i run the following function

```
def chicalcultor(theoretical, observed, errors):
  chi = 0
  
  for num in range(580):
    chi += ((pow(theoretical[num] - observed[num], 2)) / (pow(errors[num], 2)))
  return chi
```

I get this error

```
      5   for num in range(580):
----> 6     chi += ((pow(theoretical[num] - observed[num], 2)) / (pow(errors[num], 2)))
      7   return chi
      8 

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Could someone tell me where im going wrong?

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: all three inputs are lists